# Chorded keyboards for programming

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am trying to find a chorded keyboard layout that is a good fit for programmers. I do a lot of work in emacs & screen on languages like c, c++, python and node.js so they all have a similar "ends in semicolon" style.

I have found many chorded layouts but no layouts that really focus on programming. Is it possible that the addition of the special characters makes the charset to large to chord?

If I can find one that suits my needs I am making an ergonomic keyboard with trackball that way I can sit in a normal spine position and not put my chair on plywood to match my desk height all day...

Comment: Have you thoght about getting a height adjustable chair or table? I have both adjustable. I'm able to work while sitting and standing. Sometimes I stand on a balance borad. The table and chair are each on wheels. The monitor is on an 3D adjustable arm. All very flexible and ergonomic. I love it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell if this is a question about ergonomics or something else. I'm sure you know that a lot of people who keyboard a lot like Dvorak because of reduced finger movement. Have you tried it.

I use this keyboard for it's physical adjustability but each key is actually 100% programmable, too, so that may get you what you need.

http://www.fentek-ind.com/Comfort-keyboard.htm#.Vti1yPkrIgs